# (Wordpress) Catalog with categorized articles

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages, wordpress-gutenberg

I'm building a review site for local restaurants. I want to write articles that are categorized something like: brewery, city x, vegan, etc.

The visitors would have to select from a menu the categories they are interested in and on the page should appear the articles that have all the attributes they selected.

The problem is that I do not know how to create such a catalog... Any help, please?

My site is built with Elementor if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

When you say the word: "Categorized" - this means you are referring to Custom Taxonomies (worth researching).

You can point-and-click to add custom post types (e.g. Restraunt), then register Custom Taxonomies (e.g. Diet Types, Price Level, City, etc).  This will also help with SEO if done properly.

You can expand your Restaurant's meta data too with ACF (Advanced Custom Fields), and add open_hours, etc.

Elementor actually has integrations with ACF ... so you can drop elements, and bind their value to the post-meta value too!  Allowing you to build highly customized "single post" templates for your Restaurant post type.